# Name 'not defined' even though it is, in a separate function

Tags: python

I have a part of a bigger program here:

```
from random import randint

def computerChooses():
    import random
    choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    computerChoice = choices[randint(0,2)]




def whoWins():
    if computerChoice == "rock":
                print("DO THIS")
    elif computerChoice == "paper":
                print("DO THIS")
    elif computerChoice == "scissors":
                print("DO THIS")

computerChooses()
whoWins()
```

I always end up with:

```
NameError: name 'computerChoice' is not defined
```

(even though I believe it is!)

This, the error message states, is for line 20, and line 12.

What did  I do wrong and where, specifically?

Thanks,
Khy

Comment: Make computerChoice a global variable. Add 'global computerChoice' in the beginning of the function computerChooses().

Answer (score -1):

```
from random import randint

def computerChooses():
    import random
    choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    computerChoice = choices[randint(0,2)]

    return computerChoice




def whoWins(computerChoice):
    if computerChoice == "rock":
            print("DO THIS")
    elif computerChoice == "paper":
            print("DO THIS")
    elif computerChoice == "scissors":
            print("DO THIS")

result = computerChooses()
whoWins(result)
```